# How to make spring security make use of the existing tables by switching from in-memory

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have searched for this issue but cannot find any answer. I am new to spring framework. I have created an app which uses inMemory users. I want to switch and use the users I have created with the help of a data.sql file and be able to validate them using the Login Form.

The issue is that I do not know what I have to do manually in this situation and what spring security does automatically for myself, is processing and comparing done by spring or do I have to do it manually?.

I have a passwordEncoder, I have a datasource now since users are no longer in memory. Most of the tutorials I found on the web are describing a complete cycle of login-register "how-to" and my issue does not fit here since I do not have a register form. Trying to adapt the tutorials to what my current situation is, is very confusing. Please give me some suggestion on how to log in successfully with the data.sql users I have.

I also have to specify that I managed to save the users from the file to the database by using these in my application.propreties file

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.data=data.sql
```

data.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, password, role) VALUES ('user1','$2y$12$x6ttHRkoBggiFDS42..nleKvu/grzYnJNaoIjr6Fhja2Lch8lrwr6','USER');
INSERT INTO users (name, password, role) VALUES ('user2','$2y$12$NPwnUv.XKreK1N9/boQU2uHRvarqXwzsMvatQGu2C1MXcquJHJalW','USER');
INSERT INTO users (name, password, role) VALUES ('admin','$2y$12$vAtmAv/hYaVv2RiDmD8yYea0eUxW7MwsTYAygtzx1bXqfUvguF7xy','ADMIN');
```

user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String role;

    public User(String name, String password, String role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String password, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

thymeleaf form:

```
 <!-- LOG IN FORM -->
        <div>
            <form id="loginform" name="f" th:action="@{/loginver}" method="post">
                <fieldset id="field">
                    <legend id="please">Please Login</legend>
                    <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-success">
                        Invalid username and password
                    </div>
                    <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                        You have been logged out.
                    </div>

                    <label for="username" id="usr">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
                    <label for="password" id="pass">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>

                    <button type="submit" id="subbutton" class="btn">Log in</button>


                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin() {
//        System.out.println("IN LOGIN");
//        User user = userRepository.findByName("user1");
//        System.out.println(user.getName());
//        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
//        System.out.println(user.getRole());
        return "login4";
    }
```

security config

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/webjars/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resources/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/fonts/**", "/scss/**", "/index", "/", "/login").permitAll()
                //this is enabling request on static resources which are blocked by spring security automatically.
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()           
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login4.html")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Comment: Why did you post this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739748/spring-securityconfiguring-security-to-accept-and-use-manually-added-users-via ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Spring Security\]Configuring security to accept and use manually added users via a .sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739748/spring-securityconfiguring-security-to-accept-and-use-manually-added-users-via)

Comment: it is not a duplicate. i managed to partially find a solution for half of the problem in that thread. I openend a new one because i need help to make spring security work with the new added users.Can you help me with this/?